# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException:The path to the driver executable must be set by the : system property

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException : The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html  
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:199)  
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:109)  
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$0(ChromeDriverService.java:1)  
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:137)   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:296)   
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:88)     at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:116)    
at practise_locators.DatePicker.main(DatePicker.java:11)
```

Here is my code:

```
package practise_locators;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class DatePicker {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        System.setProperty("WebDriver.Chrome.driver", "E:\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting "The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property"though set correct path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44476647/getting-the-path-to-the-driver-executable-must-be-set-by-the-webdriver-chrome-d)

Comment: A quick google of the error message would have brought up info that would have solved your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error says it all :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException : The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html  
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:199)
```

The following phrases from the error implies that there is an error in the line containing **webdriver.chrome.driver**

The error can be either of the following :

- Error in the [*System Class Method*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) `setProperty()`(including sequence) :

  ```
  System.setProperty()
  ```

  > This line should be the very **first line** in your script.
- Error in the specified [*Key*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) :

  ```
  "WebDriver.Chrome.driver"
  ```
- Error in the *Value* field :

  ```
  "E:\\chromedriver.exe"
  ```

  > You have to pass the absolute path of the *WebDriver*  through either of the following options :

  - Escaping the back slash (`\\`) e.g. `"C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe"`
  - Single forward slash (`/`) e.g. `"C:/path/to/chromedriver.exe"`

Your code seems to be having two issues as follows :

- First issue is in specifying the *Key* which instead of `"WebDriver.Chrome.driver"` should have been **`"webdriver.chrome.driver"`** as follows :

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\chromedriver.exe");
  ```
- Second issue is in the *sequence* of mentioning the *Key* **`"webDriver.chrome.driver"`** in your program which should be before **`WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();`** as follows :

  ```
  System.setProperty("WebDriver.Chrome.driver", "E:\\chromedriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.get("https://www.google.com");
  ```

Comment: I agree that it is all about the provided PATH of the driver. Mac and Windows work differently, so you must check the / and \ as well as the folder structure.

Answer (score 1):

Download the chromedriver version corresponding to the chrome version in your system from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads . Unzip the file and run the below code in the IDE.

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Selintroduction {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Invoking browser
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

}
```

}

(Path would depend on your file location in the PC.)

Comment: thanks, but this is a duplication answer to the answer above

Answer (score 0):

I have seen many people are using wrong sequence.
the sequence  should be.

1. First set the property and then launch the browser

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:/chrome/chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

```
      driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error when my code was like so:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\abs\\chromedriver_win32.exe");
```

It works after adding `"chromedriver"` before `".exe"` like so:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\abs\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

if the path is not working, please use latest selenium webdriver like 4.10 and
use above code

Comment: Please surround the code in ``` characters to make it clearly formatted for stack overflow