# Multiple markers error when using System.setProperty in Cucumber Step Defination

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, cucumber

Error are as under:-

```
Multiple markers at this line

- Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodDeclaration
- Syntax error on token ".", @ expected after this token
- Syntax error, insert "Identifier (" to complete MethodHeaderName
- Syntax error on token ",", < expected
- Syntax error, insert "SimpleName" to complete QualifiedName
```

System.setProperty is a part of which jar file or where it is present? so that I can access it and use in my program.

```
public class Loginstepdef {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\Selenium\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();


        @Given("^I am on the login page of the application$")
        public void output()throws InterruptedException
        {
            driver.get("https://motzie-staging.mobile-recruit.com/login");
            //Navigation navigator=driver navigator();
            //navigator.to(http://10.10.5.56/login);

        }

        @When("^I login with username (.*) and password(.*)$")
        public void output2(String username, String password) throws InterruptedException 
        {
            //WebElement loginfield = driver.findElement(By.className("ng-scope"));
            WebElement loginfield = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
            loginfield.sendKeys(username);
            loginfield.sendKeys(password);
            WebElement loginbutton = driver.findElement(By.className("ng-scope"));  
            loginbutton.click();
        }

        @Then("^Login successfully in that account$")
        public void output3() throws InterruptedException
        {
            System.out.print("login successfully");
        }

}
```

Comment: I have also tried with / and \\ but the error remains same i.e

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\Selenium\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");

please provide solution ASAP.

Comment: You have missing `)` somewhere, not in the code you posted.

Comment: I have posted the exact code that I have tried.

Comment: You can't use `System.setProperty` outside method scope.

Comment: so what can i write to prevent it from error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Key* and the *Value* with in **`System.setProperty`** are from Java [System Class Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) and both accepts *String* values. Hence pressing `ctrl+space` won't fetch you optimum results.

The error you are seeing is coming out of the *Value* field :

```
"E:\Selenium\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe"
```

You have to pass the absolute path of the *WebDriver* variant through either of the following options:

- Escaping the back slash (`\\`) e.g. `"E:\\Selenium\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe"`
- Single forward slash (`/`) e.g. `"E:/Selenium/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe"`

> **Note** : You can find a detailed discussion in [Exception in thread “main” java.lang.IllegalStateException:The path to the driver executable must be set by the : system property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49350091/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-illegalstateexceptionthe-path-to-the-drive/49356246#49356246)

---

### Update

When you are using `cucumber` you have to put the initialization part of *WebDriver* within a method scope as follows :

```
WebDriver driver;

@Given("^Open Firefox and Start Application$")
public void Open_Firefox_and_Start_Application() throws Throwable 
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\Selenium\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver =  new ChromeDriver();
}
```

Comment: I have also tried with / and \\ but the error remains same i.e

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\Selenium\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");

please provide solution ASAP.

Comment: @RomitGupta Update the question with your current code block for further analysis.

Comment: I have updated my question, please check it out and provide any solution ASAP.

Comment: ok, I have uploaded the code block.Now you can look into the issue

Comment: Yes, you are right, the error has been removed, thanks for providing the solution

Answer (score 0):

`\` is used for escape sequence, so it's giving you an error. Use `/` or `\\` in the path

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\Selenium\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
```

Comment: I have also tried with / and \\ but the error remains same i.e System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\Selenium\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe"); please provide solution ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Issue raised because you write it wrong. Use **" \\ "** or **" /"**

("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\Selenium\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");

Comment: I have also tried with / and \\ but the error remains same i.e System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\Selenium\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe"); please provide solution ASAP.

Answer (score -1):

Write it in main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();;
    String url ="https://www.gmail.com";
    driver.get(url);
```