# can't run selenium test on vs code

Tags: java, selenium

```
     import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
     import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("hi"); 
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        driver.quit(); 
    }
}
```

I imported jar file for selenium and downloaded right webchrome drive and it give me error

```
PS D:\software testing task 2>  & 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.1\bin\java.exe' '-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages' '@C:\Users\mohamed\AppData\Local\Temp\cp_apvu20bu2lqgd550a094p3mwf.argfile' 'App' 
zzzzzzzzzz
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
        at org.openqa.selenium.internal.Require$StateChecker.nonNull(Require.java:311)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:135)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:38)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:231)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:437)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:127)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:48)
        at App.main(App.java:7)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Driver path should be set before browser launch as given below.
>
> ```
> System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\List_of_Jar\chromedriver.exe");
> WebDriver wd =new ChromeDriver();
> String baseUrl = "https://www.google.com";
> wd.get(baseUrl);"
> ```

[Getting "The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property"though set correct path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44476647/getting-the-path-to-the-driver-executable-must-be-set-by-the-webdriver-chrome-d)

The path to the driver executable must be set by the **webdriver.chrome.driver system property**; for more information:

```
System.setProperty("<Path to>chromedriver.exe");
```

Answer (score 0):

Absolute Path: `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\List_of_Jar\chromedriver.exe");`

Relative Path:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"./Driver\\chromedriver.exe");
```

Path to the driver must be set before webdriver object creation and check browser version and chromedriver version.